# Is there any performance gain by including columns with default values in insert statements?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE [FooTable](
[foo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[foo_boo] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[foo_date] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
)
```

Is there any performance gain to include the defaults for an insert, like this

```
INSERT INTO [FooTable]
([foo],[foo_boo],[foo_date])
VALUES
('FooBar', 0, GETDATE())
```

Over letting the defaults do their thing

```
INSERT INTO [FooTable] ([foo])
VALUES ('FooCooYoo')
```

I assume it's negligible, but was just wondering.

Thanks!

Comment: The execution plans are nearly identical. Both have a call to `getdate()`. The only difference I see is that because they both are auto parameterised the first one has an additional check that `[foo_boo]` is not being passed a `NULL` value which is omitted in the second as this is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing worth mentioning.

Additionally, in the spirit of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) I'd also say that it is bad practice.  2 years on, you (or the person who succeeds you in the job) will be scratching your head wondering why changing the column's default didn't change the value inserted.